# Keeping file open in R

Tags: r, file-writing

After executing write.csv the file connection is closed, because of which whenever I write data into the file, the old data is lost.
But I want to keep writing data into the file without losing the old data.
How do I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, Code

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the argument `append = TRUE`.

Have a look at `?write.csv`

**EDIT**:

As @r.bot suggested using `write.table` might be a better option that `write.csv` which might return an error. More info [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-July/245840.html).

Comment: I'm dont think that append works for csv files. I just tested it and got the message `attempt to set 'append' ignored`. It works for `write.table` though

Comment: You're right. I'll edit my answer.